# CPU and RAM usage statistics for iPhone/iOS (similar to Activity Monitor)?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, performance, activity-monitor

Is there any (preferably free) way to view CPU and RAM usage by process (e.g. app) on iPhone without jailbreaking the device?

Activity Monitor on macOS displays

- Process Name
- % CPU (per core I believe)
- CPU Time
- Threads

and some other CPU statistics, as well as these RAM statistics:

- Process Name
- Memory (GB)
- Threads

It would be great to know how to view similar statistics on iPhone.

Comment: I found a whole bunch of apps by searching for "activity monitor iOS." Also, I would imagine that XCode offers these kind of tools so you can troubleshoot the apps you are building for iOS and see how they are "behaving" on an iPhone or iPad.

Answer (score 5):

I use [CPU-x Dasher](https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/cpu-x-dasher-z-battery-life/id1359763765) for this. It displays :

- CPU usage, frequency time
- RAM usage (free/used/reserved…)
- Benchmark took (not that much features but it’s still a benchmark)
- Networks/Sensors data
- And all of this can be integrated on a widget

It’s still limited compared to some Android apps and it has a lot of ads but it’s the best I could find yet.